# button click event from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

So I have this web application that our customers use.  It is like xxx.mydomain.com.  I have another web application that is like yyy.mydomain.com.  So what I want to do is have a hidden div with iframe on xxx.mydomain.com whereby when a user clicks on a button on xxx.mydomain.com this "floating" div with iframe (which src is yyy.mydomain.com) will display over top of the screen of xxx.mydomain.com.

We are doing this versus opening a new window so that the user feels like they are the same experience.  It will feel like the second program is part of the first program.  So all of this is working fine.

So on the second program (yyy.domain.com displayed in iframe) I have a button that basically tells them to go back to the main program.  I want to be able to capture this button click event and hide this "floating" div with iframe so the user then sees the screen of the main program.

How do I go about doing this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your second app is always in the iframe, you can call functions from the parent document using:

```
parent.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind event over button but as it is iframe,trick is to select content of iframe then find button over it to hide parent of iframe.
code:

```js
$('body iframe').contents().find('.backButton').bind('click',function(e) {
  //lets parent of iframe is having parent class
  $('.parent').hide();
 });
```

Comment: So should ur code be in the host page?  or in the page of the second app that is in the iframe?